# Why won't $http.put in AngularJS work?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

I currently have the following angular script in a page:

```js
var app = angular.module('doorman', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.create = function() {
    var msg = '{' +
      '"id":"id",' +
      '"building":"' + $scope.building + '",' +
      '"unit":"' + $scope.unit + '",' +
      '"firstName":"' + $scope.firstName + '",' +
      '"name":"' + $scope.name + '",' +
      '"carrier":"' + $scope.carrier + '",' +
      '"tracker":"' + $scope.tracker + '"' +
      '"delivered":"0",' +
      '"added":"NOW()"' +
      '}';
    $http.put("104.131.166.246:8080/doorman/rest/pilot", msg).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //empty the fields
      $scope.building = "";
      $scope.unit = "";
      $scope.firstName = "";
      $scope.name = "";
      $scope.carrier = "";
      $scope.tracker = "";
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //TODO temporary, remove
      alert("ERROR " + status + ": " + data);
    });
  };
  $scope.search = function() {

  }
});
```

I have a backend RESTful java servlet handling requests.
When I call the 'create()' function, the output always ends up on the error function, showing the alert 'ERROR undefined: undefined'. While monitoring http requests on chrome, I see no request being made at all. What could the problem be?

Comment: Side note: with $http your msg aka data. Should be a javascript object literal not a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Apparently, appending "http://" to the beginning of the url is necessary. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's absolutely necessary.  Angular won't assume a protocol. I was about to post an answer to that effect, but you found the error yourself. Well done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From angular side, your code looks ok. Further when you say the call ends up in the error section, it suggest that something is going wrong on the outbound call or on the server side. Can you use **browser tools** or if you are in windows use a tool like **fiddler** to see the network traffic to see what’s going on. One

other thing, see whether you have to enable Cross-origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on server side.

Cheers

Comment: Just tried fiddler, result is the same as chrome: no request is made at all. That means the problem is definitely client-side.